# Autodesk webhook not firing all the event at once

Tags: php, webhooks, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I am using the * hook `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/data/events/*/hooks`

When I try to upload 100 files only 27 `dm.version.added` is firing, and not all 100 events are firing.

any solution,
there is no error showing

Comment: Hi Vikas, just checking before report back to Webhooks team, version added events happens to the specified folder, are all the new added files under the same folder? Or you registered the events for all the folders you are interested? Are you able to reproduce the issue consistently?

Comment: Hello @ZhongWu I have resolved the issue, there is the throttle is applied on the laravel application due to which not all the webhooks coming

Comment: cool, thanks for your update.